# find: paths must precede expression: `.'find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-exec'?

Tags: command-line, sed

i need to execute in background this command

```
sudo find '/abc/abc/' -type f -exec sed 's/domain1\it/domain2\com/g' '{}' \; . &
```

but I have two issues:

```
find: paths must precede expression: `.'
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-exec'?
```

And again, there are other smart ways to "find and replace" more fastly, to do this: **sudo find '/abc/abc/' -type f -exec sed 's/domain1\it/domain2\com/g' '{}' ; &** maybe with grep?

Thanks

Comment: What's the `.` supposed to be, there?

Comment: Is `/abc/abc/` an existing directory? Where are the files to be searched. The "`paths must preceed

Comment: Ok, removed "." before &, abc/abc it is ok, but with "/abc/abc/" it shows the fully process and i don't want it, i need it in background

Comment: @DantinoEsposito background processes still write their standard output and error streams to the terminal - and `sed` writes to standard output unless you add the `-i` or `--in-place` option.

Comment: Ok for -i, now background is ok, but i checked and with sudo find "/abc/abc/" -type f -exec sed -i "s/domain\it/domain\com/g" '{}' \; & nothing domain has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Is `/abc/abc/` an existing directory? Where are the files to be searched? The "`paths must preceed..` " message is a crypto-mesage. Decoded it means that the first (or first several) parameter to `find` is not a directory tree for `find` to traverse. Since the rest of the parameters are "`find` expressions", that's what it complains about.

The command you're `-exec`ing needs to be terminated by a semicolon (`;`). But, since a semicolon would terminate (the parsing of) the `find` command,  `-exec`'s semicolon must be escaped with a backslash (`\`). thus

`-exec ...command... \;`

    
  
Welcome to the world of `find` magic. Re-read `man find`.

Your `sed` expression is wrong. It should be:

```
 sed -e 's/domain1\.it/domain2\.com/'
```

The backslash (`\`) simply flips the "special handling" flag on the next character, so `domain1\it` matches "`domain1it`", not "`domain1.it`". "`\i`" isn't special, so it's treated like "`i`".

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Done, i added the second point in my Questions. Thanks.

Comment: About your reply, i checked and with sudo find "/abc/abc/" -type f -exec sed -i "s/domain\it/domain\com/g" '{}' \; & nothing domain has been changed.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.